# Filling empty auto increment values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a table with this structure:

> |id|name|

**id** is incrementing when I add a new row in my table.
For example i've got 3 rows:

```
1|John
2|Bob
3|Alice
```

If i will **DELETE** row with id **2** there will be that:

```
1|John
3|Alice
```

How to **INSERT** a new row with id = **2** if I won't know what id's are empty?

(Or - How to insert rows with unused id (auto increment) values?)

Thanks.

Comment: but this will create a problem to your relational table why  you want to insert rows in unused id?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query to get the least unused id.

```
   SELECT (Min(ID) + 1) AS NewIDToInsert 
   FROM TableName T2A
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TableName T2B WHERE T2A.ID + 1 = T2B.ID)
```

Comment: The AUTOINCREMENT keyword does not affect this either way. The result `7` does not match the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually the one more than the largest ROWID currently
>   in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

In other words, you should be able to specify the `id` explicitly when performing the insert and it won't autoincrement.

Comment: The question is how to determine the value of the explicitly specified ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26930501/7032856), I've written a stored procedure that works on [mysql-5.7](/questions/tagged/mysql-5.7) that fills empty ids with the maximum ids.

## Usage

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tableName
;
CALL sp_fill_empty_ids('tableName');
```

---

## Implementation

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_fill_empty_ids(IN tableName VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  SET @minEmptyId := 0;
  SET @maxId := 0;

  CALL statement(CONCAT('
  SET @maxId = (
    SELECT MAX(Id)
    FROM ', tableName,'
  );
  '));
  CALL statement(CONCAT('
    SET @minEmptyId = (
      SELECT (Min(ID) + 1) AS NewIDToInsert
      FROM ', tableName,' T2A
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM ', tableName,' T2B WHERE T2A.ID + 1 = T2B.ID)
    );
  '));
  WHILE ( @minEmptyId <> (@maxId + 1) ) DO
    CALL statement(CONCAT('
      SET @minEmptyId = (
        SELECT (Min(ID) + 1) AS NewIDToInsert
        FROM ', tableName,' T2A
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM ', tableName,' T2B WHERE T2A.ID + 1 = T2B.ID)
      );
    '));

    CALL statement(CONCAT('
    --     SELECT * FROM
        UPDATE
          ', tableName, '
        SET Id = @minEmptyId
        WHERE Id = @maxId
        ;
    '));

    SET @maxId = @minEmptyId
    ;

  END WHILE;
  CALL statement(CONCAT('
    ALTER TABLE ', tableName,'
    AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @minEmptyId))
  ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Implementation for `statement`:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE statement(IN dynamic_statement TEXT)
BEGIN
      SET @dynamic_statement := dynamic_statement;
      PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
      EXECUTE prepared_statement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```